# Electronics Newbies's Guide to Setup Adafruit PCA9685 16 Channel Servo Driver for Raspberry Pi

Tags: hardware, pwm, servo

As a way into getting myself back into learning more about electronics I'm trying to figure out how not to screw up configuring an Adafruit 16-Channel 12-bit PWM/Servo Driver with my pi. It's been that long since I've done anything of this nature I'm a little shy over starting to plug things in. I have the equipment from the [article on AdaFruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-servo-driver-with-raspberry-pi?view=all) and am trying to follow it.

If I get it right, I'll need to solder some pieces (such as the power adapter on the breakout board), but I'm not quite sure what and can't find a good run through of setting up the equipment.

I guess my questions are,

Any good guide on how to read that wiring diagram properly?, because I'm left a little confused as to how the breakout board attaches to the breadboard.

Any good walk through tutorials on this stuff? I have found a lot of videos, but none specific to this case. I wish pluralsight had a getting started with electronics course!

I didn't feel that this was jumping in from the deep-end first, but if so, I'm open to advice. I tried to find relevant questions, so I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: Despite what adafruit say you do not need additional hardware to provide PWM to multiple servos. [pigpio](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/) will let you drive as many servos as you can find spare gpios.  No soldering required.

Comment: Thanks @joan. Is there anywhere I can go that is good for talking about this stuff? IRC etc?

Comment: If you look at my profile i have some questions that have already been answered in regards to pwm and servo control (using phone app so cant get url)