# AdaFruit ServoKit CircuitPython Blinka Library Installation Problem

Tags: raspbian, python, python-3, servo, adafruit

I'm follow along with a tutorial to get started with using CircuitPython to control servos on my RaspberryPi (https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-pwm-servo-hat-for-raspberry-pi/using-the-python-library), but during the installation I get an error that I can't seem to fix or find any information on. After installing Blinka and then proceeding on to install CircuitPython, I am met with an error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ sudo pip install adafruit-circuitpython-servokit
Collecting adafruit-circuitpython-servokit
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/86/2d/a8ebfc83d88f121569c950b960734d72d00d404b085899b16626be58648b/adafruit-circuitpython-servokit-1.1.0.tar.gz
Collecting Adafruit-Blinka (from adafruit-circuitpython-servokit)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Adafruit-Blinka (from adafruit-circuitpython-servokit) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Adafruit-Blinka (from adafruit-circuitpython-servokit)
```

Not really sure where to go with fixing this issue so I figured maybe someone with more experience could point me in the right direction

Comment: Welcome and nice to meet you! I have also been trying to use Rpi3/4 MicroPython and CircuitPython to control AdaFruit's PCA9685 16 Channel PWM / Servo Board. There are a couple of version incompatibility problems if you are using Rpi4B buster. There has also been huge confusion between Circuit Python and MicroPython versions of AdaFruit Blinka. Anyway, just now I have successfully installed AdaFruit CircuitPython Blinka on my Rpi4B buster (2019spe26 release) and you might like to read the installation record in my answer.  Good luck and cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Adafruit-Blinka [requires Python 3](https://pypi.org/project/Adafruit-Blinka/).
It seems you're trying to install it for Python 2, using `pip`.

Use `pip3` as instructed in the tutorial you link to.

```
sudo pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-servokit
```

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

> How to fix AdaFruit CircuitPython Blinka Servo Board Installation Problem?

---

***Answer***

There are many reasons for not successfully installing CircuitPython Blinka, including the following:

> (1) Not using pip3,
>
> (2) Not using latest version of raspbian update and upgrade

I have successfull installed Blinka and CircuitPython on Rpi4B buster (release 2019sep26).  I have also made a summary for you to compare and contrast your installation.  You can also read the full installation record in *[Reference 2](https://penzu.com/p/13ff0e7d)* below:

*Circuit Python and Blinka Installation Summary*

> pi@tlfong01:~ $ date Sun 03 Nov 2019 09:51:49 AM HKT
>
> pi@tlfong01:~ $ uname -a Linux tlfong01 4.19.75-v7l+ #1270 SMP Tue Sep
>   24 18:51:41 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
>
> pi@tlfong01:~ $ sudo apt-get update
>
> pi@tlfong01:~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade
>
> pi@tlfong01:~ $ sudo pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
>
> pi@tlfong01:~ $ pip3 install RPI.GPIO
>
> pi@tlfong01:~ $ pip3 install adafruit-blinka

*Successfully installed Adafruit-PlatformDetect-1.3.4
Adafruit-PureIO-0.2.3 **adafruit-blinka-3.0.0** rpi-ws281x-4.2.2
sysv-ipc-1.0.0*

---

***References***

(1) [Installing AdaFruit CircuitPython Blinka Libraries on Raspberry Pi - Lada Ada](https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-on-raspberrypi-linux/installing-circuitpython-on-raspberry-pi)

(2) ***[CircuitPython Blinka Rpi4B buster Installation Record - tlfong01](https://penzu.com/p/13ff0e7d)***

(3) [Adafruit MicroPython (Not CircuitPython) Blinka Installation Problem - drfuzzyness 2018sep15](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_LIS3DH/issues/48)

(4) [Adafruit Blinka For Non CircuitPython Python Such As Linux and MicroPython - pyPi](https://pypi.org/project/Adafruit-Blinka/)

(5) [Adafruit_Blinka Updated Bus IO Error Type - AdaFruit Blinka GitHub](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Blinka/releases)

(6) [Rpi4B buster CircuitPython Blinka Servo Board Installation Problem](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101095/rpi4b-buster-bno055-9-dof-sensor-and-16-channel-pwm-driver-circuitpython-program)

(7) [Electronics Newbies's Guide to Setup Adafruit PCA9685 16 Channel Servo Driver for Raspberry Pi - @Hammerstein 2014sep10](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23224/beginning-with-servos-and-pwm)

(8) [AdaFruit Python Installation of PCA9685 ServoKit Library - Kevin Townsend 2012aug16](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-servo-driver-with-raspberry-pi?view=all)

---

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - [Differences between CircuitPython Blinka and MicroPython Blinka](https://pypi.org/project/Adafruit-Blinka/)*

*Introduction*

This repository contains a selection of packages mirroring the CircuitPython API on hosts running micropython.

> board - breakout-specific pin identities
>
> microcontroller - chip-specific pin identities
>
> digitalio - digital input/output pins, using pin identities from
>   board+microcontroller packages
>
> bitbangio - software-driven interfaces for I2C, SPI
>
> busio - hardware-driven interfaces for I2C, SPI, UART
>
> time - substitute functions monkey-patched to time module

*Dependencies*

The Micropython compatibility layers described above are intended to provide a CircuitPython-like API for devices which are running CPython or Micropython.

---

*End of answer*